# Compute $H^1$ norm of a two variable function

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces

I have an exercise on my book, where's written:

> Let $\Omega =B_1(0)$ and $$f(x,y)=|\log(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}})|^k$$
> for $k \in (0, \frac{1}{2})$. Prove that the $H^1$ norm squared is $$||f||_{H^1}^2 = 2 \pi \int_0^1 |\log(s)|^{2k}s ds + 2k^2 \pi^2 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{s}|\log(s)|^{2k -2}ds$$

- The first term is just the $L^2$ norm of $f$, and I have been able to show it. My big big problem is the **second term**, which should correspond to $$\sum_{\alpha \leq 1} \int_{B_1(0)} (D^{\alpha}f)^2$$

**Question**: in this particular case, is the above summation just $$\int \int_{B_1(0)} (\partial_x f)^2 + (\partial_y f)^2 dxdy$$?

If so, I have problems in obtaining the expected result. For instance, if I compute the $L^2$ norm of the first partial I obtain the following ([wolframapha computation of the derivative](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28d%2Fdx+%7Clog%281%2F%28sqrt%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%29%29%7C%5Ek%29%5E2))

$$\int_{B_1(0)} (\partial_x f)^2 =k^2 \int_0^{2 \pi} \cos^2(\theta) d\theta \int_0^1 \frac{1}{s} |\log(s)|^{2k-2} = k^2 \pi \int_0^1 \frac{1}{s} |\log(s)|^{2k-2}ds$$

The other integral for $\partial_y f$ is analogous, and hence my second addendum would be

$$\color{blue}{2} k^2 \pi \int_0^1 \frac{1}{s} |\log(s)|^{2k-2}ds$$

I can't figure out how to get that $\color{red}{\pi^2}$ factor.

Comment: Looks right to me at a glance

Comment: @CalvinKhor thanks for your check. If you look at Wolfram derivative, you'll see that the there are two $\log$ factors, one with the absolute value, the other without. May it be the problem, eventually?

Comment: I don’t think so. Sorry I can’t see the issue either

Comment: I don't think that the $2$ in one of the logarithms is a composition actually @CalvinKhor

Comment: Yeah sorry that was a blunder :) hence the deleted comment

Comment: Oh, btw, one last question: when we have $$\sum_{\alpha \leq 1} \int_{B_1(0)} (D^{\alpha}f)^2$$ do we have to sum for every possible combination of $\alpha$s? In this example, we have $\alpha = (0,1)$ and $\alpha = (1,0)$, so I used both of them in the summation. Is this correct? @CalvinKhor

Comment: Yes that’s right